# Did I leave anything out?

Tags: translation

How would you ask "did I leave anything out?" in Italian? Like, if I made a list of things and I want to know if I did not include something that I was supposed to. I am thinking "non messo qualcosa?" ma non lo so.

Answer (score 7):

Commonly you will hear a more active form of the expression with the verb "dimenticare"

> Ho dimenticato qualcosa?
>
> Dimentico qualcosa?

A more sophisticated (and somewhat quaint/formal) expression that is similar to what you have suggested uses the verb "omettere" (to omit).

> Ho omesso qualcosa dalla/nella lista?

As Denis suggested, watch out with the pronunciation between "ho" and "omesso".

As DaG suggested, something similar to what you had in mind which I had not thought about is

> C'è qualcosa che non ho messo/incluso?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the verb *omettere*: it's quite formal and easy to mishear as *mettere* (with exactly the opposite meaning!), especially after a word ending in *-o*.

Comment: Granted, it is quite formal, although I personally use it quite a lot, even in everyday contexts. And yes, one must have a mastery with respect to pronunciation to use it in the sentence above.

Comment: +1 for _omettere/omesso_, both in itself and because is possibly the word the OP tried to remember. Or perhaps he had in mind something like _C'è qualcosa che non ho messo?_

Comment: @Dag good point, didn't think about it! I will edit the answer with your comments for the sake of completeness